# What is the distance between the line with Cartesian equation $x - 4 = y - 5 = z$ and the line with Cartesian equation $x - 2 = y - 5 = z - 1$?

Tags: vectors

What is the distance between the line with Cartesian equation $x - 4 = y - 5 = z$ and the line with Cartesian equation $x - 2 = y - 5 = z - 1$?

I am not sure how to do it. I think the lines are parallel with the same direction but I'm not sure.

Comment: Find the equation of a plane to which the these two parallel lines are perpendicular. Then compute the point of intersection of each line with that plane. Your problem then is reduced to finding the Euclidean distance between two points.

Comment: Hints on finding the equation of that plane. You can find the equation of the plane that passes through the point $(4,5,0)$  on the first line or the plane that passes through the point $(2,5,1)$ on the other line. And the vector (1,1,1) (wigh is parallel to both lines) is a normal to the plane. So if $(x,y,z)$ is any point on the plane, then the two vectors $(x-5,y-5,z)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are orthogonal and have zero scalar product...

Comment: Hints on finding the intersection of a plane with a line that is not parallel to it. Parameterize the equation of the line, then substitute in the equation of the plane. Solve for the parameter. Finally, substitute for the value of the parameter in the parameterization of the line.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

The vector equation of the first line can be written as
\begin{align*}
L_{1}(a) = (a,a+1,a-4) = (0,1,-4) + a(1,1,1)
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the vector equation of the second line can be written as
\begin{align*}
L_{2}(b) = (b,b+3,b-1) = (0,3,-1) + b(1,1,1)
\end{align*}

Consequently the lines $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ are parallel.

In order to calculate the distance between them, let us take $(0,3,-1) - (0,1,-4) = (0,2,3)$.

Hence the distance $d$ can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
d = \left\|(0,2,3) - \frac{1}{3}\langle(0,2,3),(1,1,1)\rangle(1,1,1)\right\|
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is a clever idea. $v:=(0,2,3)$ is a vector that starts from one line and ends at the other. The subtraction of $v$ and its projection in the direction parallel to the lines is orthogonal to both lines and starts from one line and ends at the other. So its length of the difference is the required distance.

Answer (score 1):

The direction vector of both lines is $(1,1,1)$ and the unit direction vector
$\hat{v}$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt3}(1,1,1)$.

Now take a point $A$ on line $1$ and $B$ on line $2$. The easiest from the equation of lines are $A(4, 5, 0)$ and $B(2, 5, 1)$.

Given both lines are parallel, the distance $d$ between the lines is then simply $|\vec{AB} \times \hat{v}|$ (this is because if the angles between vectors is $\theta$, cross product will have the magnitude $|AB \sin \theta|$ which is the perpendicular distance between the lines).

So $d = \frac{1}{\sqrt3}|(-2, 0, 1) \times (1, 1, 1)|$